# How to solve the error: [$rootScope:infdig]?

Tags: angularjs

When I am using ng-repeats in ul's and li's I am getting the errors.

Here is my html code:

```
 <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in (myData | groupBy: 'id')">
            {{key}}
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="details in value">
                    {{details.name}}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

JS code:

```
.filter('groupBy', function () {
return function (data, key) {

    var result = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (!result[data[i][key]])
            result[data[i][key]] = [];
        result[data[i][key]].push(data[i])
    }
    alert(JSON.stringify(result));
    return result;
};
});
```

These are the errors I am getting

[image]

Comment: add `groupBy` filter code here

Comment: Which version of angular-filter do you use? Try the latest https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter/releases/tag/v0.5.15

Answer (score 0):

Try to put `track by $index` in the ng-repeat like this:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in myData track by id">
        {{key}}
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="details in value">
                {{details.name}}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

You can also `track by $index` if you have duplicates in array

```
<li ng-repeat="(key, value) in myData track by $index">
```

Comment: gruopby is a custom filter @Muhammed Neswine

Comment: can you add a fiddle?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/kltGAyiY7DZbpmUUZGyg?p=preview  @ Muhammed Neswine

Comment: Can you specify what is the expected order or output?@swathi

Answer (score 0):

The infinite digest is caused by the filter that returns a new result every time it runs through the function. You'll have to rewrite the function so that it directly modifies the original `data` argument and you return the `data` argument again.

Comment: sorry can you please explain how to rewrite the function @Giovani Vercauteren

Comment: The filter function returns a new `result` object every single time. Angular will execute the filter and receive a result. Angular will execute the filter again and notice it's not the same as the last result (because of a new object) and because it's different angular will run into an infinite loop and force stop after 10 loops.

You will have to modify the `data` argument directly and return that. Angular doesn't deep check objects/arrays, it simply checks if it's a new instance.